# Accuracy Document Embedding in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, bert-language-model, information-retrieval, doc2vec

I made use of Bert document embeddings to perform information retrieval on the CACM dataset. I achieved a very low accuracy score of around 6%. However when I used the traditional BM-25 method, the result was a lot closer to 40% which is close to the average accuracy found in literature for this dataset. This is all being performed within Apache Solr.

I also attempted to perform information retrieval using Doc2Vec and acheived similarly poor results as with BERT. Is it not advisable to use document embeddings for IR tasks such as this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Many people find document embeddings work really well for their purposes!

If they're not working for you, possible reasons include:

- insufficiency of training data
- problems in your unshown process
- different end-goals – what's your idea of 'accuracy'? – than others

It's impossible to say what's affecting your process, & raw perception of its usefulness, without far more details on what you're aiming to achieve, and then doing.

Most notably, if there's other published work using the same dataset, and a similar definition of 'accuracy' on which the other published work claims a far better result using the same methods as give worse results for you, then it's more likely that there are errors in your implementation.

You'd have to name the results you're trying to match (ideally with links to the exact writeups), & show the details of what your code does, for others to have any chance of guessing what's happening for you.

Comment: Hi! So, by accuracy, I mean the calculating the actual traditional accuracy score when seeing the predicted relevant documents vs the actual relevant documents. Re: Bert, I have not trained it myself, but instead I used the most popular pretrained uncased model from huggingface. I did train the doc2vec myself on the same dataset though. I found that traditional information retrieval methods like tf-idf and bm-25 achieved a better accuracy on my test datasets, CISI and CACM. I don't have much to compare with as I can't find others attempting document embedding on these datasets

Comment: Update. I have tried S-BERT instead of BERT, and I got great results. If anyone seems to have the same issue as I did, try S-BERT.

Comment: That's a good tip about S-BERT, but without details of what was trained/tested, the possibility that the earlier BERT, or Doc2Vec, were applied in buggy ways remains strong.

Comment: I trained the doc2vec model on the CACM dataset (the documents not the queries, obviously). Depending on the hyperparameters I used, it got between 1 and 6% accuracy. With Bert, I used the pretrained Bert as a service on the same CACM dataset. It also achieved an accuracy of 6%. I did debug extensively, and I'm quite confident that there was no glaring issue. I used Apache Solr and the Solr Vector Query plugin to perform the searches.

Comment: When I tried S-BERT, I got a 37% accuracy with the default model listed in their documentation. I am now going through all their models, and I have found one that achieved a 40% accuracy. My intention now will be to use regular bm-25 for the company's actual requirements, and boost the results through the boost function parameter with the S-BERT values. I will see if this improves accuracy or not

Comment: Again, without the full code & details of how you're training, & testing accuracy, it could very easily be deeper errors.

Comment: For example, searching for [`CACM dataset`] implies you might be using the material at <http://ir.dcs.gla.ac.uk/resources/test_collections/cacm/>. From a quick glance, that appears to be about 3200 articles, most with only short titles to reflect their topics, & perhaps 220k total training words (but many of those are boilerplate metadata that isn't amenable to dense-embedding-topic-modeling). That's very, very thin for training a `Doc2Vec` model from scratch - published work tends to use tens of thousands of distinct texts, each w/ 100s or 1000s of words: many millions of training words.

Comment: If using `query.text` etc in that package in your eval, those are minimal & of a form that'd benefit from significant massaging as input to topic-based embedding-based search evaluation.  For example, they're rambling in a style uncommon from users accustomed to the keyword search fields of the last 30y; they use words/abbreviations poorly represented, in the trraining texts. They mix queries better handled by exact metadata modeling (like requests for an exact author's works) with fuzzier queries. Any eval scores will thus be very sensitive to all the implementation choices you've not shown.

Comment: My use case is similar to a help-desk style search. Are there any other datasets you would recommend ?

Comment: Your own data from your actual usage scenario, with your own slowly-growing set of realistic queries & desired results, will provide the best readout on which algorithms will work well for your data/goals.